# Building phonegap project in eclipse

Tags: android, gwt, cordova

I have built a phone gap project in eclipse and it runs fine on my device. I have also built a gwt app and I can drop the js it generates into my phonegap app and it runs fine. What I want now is to create my ui/app using get and have it deploy the generated javascript straight to my device. Is this possible in eclipse or only via an ant script?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can update the web content in your PhoneGap app without re-compiling it in Eclipse, the answer is no. The web content in your app is stored within the `.apk` and gets signed before being loaded onto your device. The `.apk` cannot be re-signed on the device.

An alternative to this is to host your app's web content on a remote server and have your PhoneGap webview load from that server location. Just set the remote location as your first parameter in your `super.loadUrl()` call.

Remember to whitelist your domain in your app settings. Documentation on whitelisting can be found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html).

Comment: What i meant was can I build an app using GWT, and then deploy it to my device and debug it while it is running on my device.

Comment: Yes, you can. With PhoneGap, your standard javascript `console.log()` calls will show up in the logcat, which will be part of the Eclipse interface.